# C++ Tree Object Class

Tags: c++, beginner, object-oriented, c++11, tree

I'm writing a class that acts as the base for almost all objects in my project. I know this class technically doesn't represent a tree structure, because it can have more than 2 children. What should I change? Should I be using smart pointers? I'm a self-taught C++ programmer, so I've got much more to learn.

Here's the declaration:

```
class Object
{
public:
    Object();
    Object(const std::string& name);
    Object(Object* const parent);
    Object(const std::string& name, Object* const parent);

public:
    virtual ~Object();

public:
    virtual void AddChild(Object* const obj) final;
    virtual void RemoveChild(Object* const obj) final;

    virtual std::vector<Object*> FindChildren(const std::string& name, const bool recursive = false) final;

    virtual Object* FindFirstChild(const std::string& name, const bool recursive = false) final;
    virtual Object* FindLastChild(const std::string& name, const bool recursive = false) final;

    virtual std::vector<std::string> ChildrenNames() const final;

    virtual bool HasChild(Object* const obj) const final;

public:
    virtual Object* GetRoot() final;

public:
    virtual bool IsRoot() const final;
    virtual bool IsParent() const final;

public:
    virtual const std::string& GetName() const final;
    virtual void SetName(const std::string& name) final;

    virtual Object* GetParent() const final;

protected:
    std::string name = unnamed_object;

protected:
    Object* parent;
    std::vector<Object*> children;
};
```

Here's the definitions:

```
Object::Object() : Object("", nullptr) {}
Object::Object(const std::string& name) : Object(name, nullptr) {}
Object::Object(Object* const parent) : Object("", parent) {}
Object::Object(const std::string& name, Object* const parent)
{
    if(!name.empty()) this->name = name;
    if(parent != nullptr) parent->AddChild(this);
}

Object::~Object()
{
    for(auto& child : children) delete child;
    children.clear();

    if(parent != nullptr) parent->children.erase(std::find(parent->children.begin(), parent->children.end(), this));
}

void Object::AddChild(Object* const obj)
{
    if(obj == nullptr) throw std::invalid_argument("The object cannot be null.");
    if(HasChild(obj)) throw std::invalid_argument("The object is already a child.");

    obj->parent = this;
    children.push_back(obj);
}

void Object::RemoveChild(Object* const obj)
{
    if(obj == nullptr) throw std::invalid_argument("The object cannot be null.");

    auto iter = std::find(children.begin(), children.end(), obj);

    if(iter == children.end()) throw std::invalid_argument("The object is not a child.");

    obj->parent = nullptr;
    children.erase(iter);
}

std::vector<Object*> Object::FindChildren(const std::string& name, const bool recursive)
{
    std::vector<Object*> result;

    for(auto& child : children)
    {
        if(name == child->name) result.push_back(child);

        if(recursive)
        {
            if(child->IsParent())
            {
                std::vector<Object*> resultRecursive = child->FindChildren(name, true);

                result.insert(result.end(), resultRecursive.begin(), resultRecursive.end());
            }
        }
    }

    return result;
}

Object* Object::FindFirstChild(const std::string& name, const bool recursive)
{
    for(auto& child : children)
    {
        if(name == child->name) return child;

        if(recursive)
        {
            if(child->IsParent()) return child->FindFirstChild(name, true);
        }
    }

    return nullptr;
}

Object* Object::FindLastChild(const std::string& name, const bool recursive)
{
    const std::vector<Object*> children = FindChildren(name, recursive);

    if(children.size() > 0)
    {
        return children.at(children.size() - 1);
    } else {
        return nullptr;
    }
}

std::vector<std::string> Object::ChildrenNames() const
{
    std::vector<std::string> result;

    for(auto& child : children) result.push_back(child->name);

    return result;
}

bool Object::HasChild(Object* const obj) const
{
    if(obj == nullptr) throw std::invalid_argument("The object cannot be null.");

    return (std::find(children.begin(), children.end(), obj) != children.end());
}

Object* Object::GetRoot()
{
    if(parent != nullptr)
    {
        return parent->GetRoot();
    } else {
        return this;
    }
}

bool Object::IsRoot() const { return (parent == nullptr); }
bool Object::IsParent() const { return (children.size() > 0); }

const std::string& Object::GetName() const { return name; }
void Object::SetName(const std::string& name)
{
    if(!name.empty())
    {
        this->name = name;
    } else {
        this->name = unnamed_object;
    }
}

Object* Object::GetParent() const { return parent; }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### There's more than binary trees

The nodes in a tree can have any number of children. Binary trees (where each node has either two or zero children) are just a special-case. So that's not something to feel bad about. Of course, I'm assuming that your application actually needs this semantics.

### A word of caution about inventing base classes

Your sentence

> I'm writing a class that acts as the base for almost all objects in my project.

made me a little worried. While it could totally be that such a type is useful for your problem, do resist the temptation to “fix” C++' lack of a base object like `java.lang.Object` in Java. If you're coming to C++ with a background in a language that has such a base type, it is time to overcome that and accept that C++ is different. Every solution has some benefits and drawbacks associated with it but if you decide to use C++, you'll likely get the worst of both worlds if you think of it as Java (or C# or Python or really any other language).

### Follow the [“Rule of Five”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4782757/rule-of-three-becomes-rule-of-five-with-c11)

If your type needs a custom destructor, it almost certainly also needs

- a custom copy constructor,
- a custom copy assignment operator

and should very likely also have

- a custom move constructor,
- a custom move assignment operator

and maybe also

- a custom `swap` overload.

Alternatively, all these operations can be `delete`d. (Which is a decent thing to do for a polymorphic type.)

In your case, if I copy an `Object` with children, the `std::vector<Object*>` will happily copy the pointers. Now, when the first of the two objects gets destroyed, it will `delete` all children and subsequent use of the other copy will invoke undefined behavior. (Even if you just dispose of it as its destructor will attempt to `delete` an already `delete`d pointer again.)

These problems will go away if instead of raw pointers (`Object*`) you use `std::unique_ptr<Object>`s. If you do this, you'll notice that you probably want to add a`virtual` `Object::clone()` member function so you can make copies of trees. Resist the temptation to simply use `std::shared_ptr<Object>` instead as it will almost certainly not do what you want. (For *immutable* trees, `std::shared_ptr<const Object>` would be a decent solution, though.)

### Rethink the combination of `virtual` and `final`

Declaring a member function as `virtual` means that a derived class can override it. Declaring a `virtual` member function as `final` means that no (further) derived class can override it again. But declaring a function in the *base class* as `virtual` and immediately `final` does no good. Just use an ordinary (non-`virtual`) function and you'll be good.

Comment: I know this is old, but I wanted to clearify that `Object` actually isn't the base class for everything, just for a certain system.